# How to skip one level of data in a sankey chart?

Tags: highcharts

Consider the following graph (the code below somehow does not work in the SO snippet, see the [equivalent Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/VdVBYE))

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: [
      ['start', 'hello', 70],
      ['start', 'world', 20],
      ['start', 'yuhu', 10],
      ['hello', 'aaa', 49],
      ['hello', 'bbb', 21],
      ['bbb', 'OK', 21],
      ['world', 'OK', 30],
      // up to now everything is OK
      // yuhu and aaa should be at the same level as OK
      ['yuhu', 'KO', 10],
      ['aaa', 'KO', 49]
    ],
    type: 'sankey',
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

If you comment out the last two elements of `data` the graph is fine. I would like to have `yuhu` and `aaa` merge at the same vertical 'layer' as `OK`.

Through tests, I found out that the next 'layer' is set up right after the current one when merging.

In my case `yuhu` and `aaa` are on different 'layers' and they cannot merge cleanly. **One solution would be for `yuhu` to extend or skip one 'layer'** (and be at the same level as `aaa`, one 'layer' before the expected landing 'layer').

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can control column that node is rendered on: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OErjZg using [`nodes`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes) options:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    nodes: [{
      id: 'KO',
      column: 3
    }],
    data: [
        ['start', 'hello', 70],
        ['start', 'world', 20],
        ['start', 'yuhu', 10],
        ['hello', 'aaa', 49],
        ['hello', 'bbb', 21],
        ['bbb', 'OK', 21],
        ['world', 'OK', 30],
        // up to now everything is OK
        // yuhu and aaa should be at the same level as OK
        ['yuhu', 'KO', 10],
        ['aaa', 'KO', 49]
    ],
    type: 'sankey', 
  }]

});
```